# p:dataTable with Dynamic Columns does not render anything

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimceFaces and want to render a table, whose number of columns are determined dynamically. I found an example here:

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml

and I think I implement it correctly, but the table is not rendered. Actually nothing is rendered at all. I debugged the programm and ascertained that:

```
CinemaSeatViewBean.getSeatsForShowList()
```

is getting called, but the method

`CinemaSeatViewBean.getDataTableColumns()`

is not called at all.

Below my code:

1.) The Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CinemaSeatViewBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private List<SeatForShow> seatsForShowList = new ArrayList<SeatForShow>();
    private List<DataTableColumn> dataTableColumns = new ArrayList<DataTableColumn>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // add SeatForShows
        ExternalContext extContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext();

        Flash flash = extContext.getFlash();
        FilmShow selectedFilmShow = (FilmShow)flash.get(FilmAndCinemaChooserBean.SELECTED_FILM_SHOW);

        int noOfColumns = selectedFilmShow.getNumberOfColumns();

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i ++){
            // prepare dynamic columns
            dataTableColumns.add(new DataTableColumn("Seat " + (i+1), "seatNo"));
        }

        for ( SeatForShow seatForShow: selectedFilmShow.getSeatsForShow()){
            seatsForShowList.add(seatForShow);
        }
    }

    public void setDataTableColumns(List<DataTableColumn> dataTableColumns) {
        this.dataTableColumns = dataTableColumns;
    }

    public List<DataTableColumn> getDataTableColumns() {
        return dataTableColumns;
    }

    public List<SeatForShow> getSeatsForShowList() {
        return seatsForShowList;
    }


    public void setSeatsForShowList(List<SeatForShow> seatsForShowList) {
        this.seatsForShowList = seatsForShowList;
    }
}
```

2.) The facelet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="seatsFormId">
        <p:dataTable id="seatsTableId" value="#{cinemaSeatViewBean.seatsForShowList}" var="seatForShow">
            <p:columns value="#{dataTableView.dataTableColumns}" var="column" sortBy="#{seatForShow[column.property]}">
                 <f:facet name="header">
                     <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
                 </f:facet>
                 <h:outputText value="#{seatForShow[column.property]}" />                      
            </p:columns>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

3.) The DataTableColumn class:

```
public class DataTableColumn implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String header;
    private String property;

    public DataTableColumn(String header, String property) {
        this.header = header;
        this.property = property;
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }
}
```

4.) I hope I enabled DEVELOPMENT_MODE correctly:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>selectFilmCinema.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Try running your application in development mode. Most likely you'll get a hint then of the error.

Comment: @Kukeltje I enabled the development mode, but nothing gets printed in the console as well

Comment: No 'bean resolved to null' or something? Are you sure this is your [mcve]? Not some other code in your project? And what do you see if you add a static column too? And a plain primeFaces `p:inputText` is shown?

Comment: @Kukeltje: I would like to hope that this is my minimal, complete example. No, no message such as bean resolved to null. Yes, <p:inputText is shown correctly. I am not quite sure how cann I add a static column in this example. Could you please help?

Comment: adding a `p:column` inside the datatable with fixed content... and sure you have `value="#{dataTableView.dataTableColumns}"` ? I would expect your IDE to give an error here and runtime too... bean name is not right

Comment: oh and the bean names you use in the first two code fragments are wrong too. Wrong casing... Please pay attention to things like this.

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you! dataTableView was wrong -  I correct it, now it works. But strange, I did not get any error! Sorry, which bean names that I use in the first two code fragments are wrong?

Comment: `CinemaSeatViewBean` should be `cinemaSeatViewBean` What is your PrimeFaces and JSF version (and imlementation). Good thing to always mention this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is a typo,

`<p:columns value="#{dataTableView.dataTableColumns}" var="column" sortBy="#{seatForShow[column.property]}">`

Should be

`<p:columns value="#{cinemaSeatViewBean.dataTableColumns}" var="column" sortBy="#{seatForShow[column.property]}">`

But your IDE should warn you for this and I expected a runtime error too (unlesss the bean actually exists in your project and does not do anything in the getter).

Comment: This was the error, right! But I did not get any warning by the IDE (Eclipse Nero) nor did I get any (run-time) error in the console. And - no - I do not have any bean ot whatever with the name dataTableView in my workspace. I am using primefaces-6.0 and jsf 2.2.12

Comment: Try if you get an error with PF 6.2 otr even 7.0 when you use the 'wrong' code. And off-topic: With JSF 2.2 you can (and should) use newer namespaces and annotations (CDI ones, not the JSF ones). That makes your code more future proof already.

Comment: I will test it and will let you know. Thank you!